# Windows Azure Development Fabric Icon not showing on System tray

Tags: azure

I've a azure web application which seems to run fine on F5. However I'm not seeing Development Fabric ICON  on system Tray.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

Also, is there any way I can start the Deveper App fabric via command prompt or any other mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your cloud project is the startup project (boldfaced) when you press F5. If your web app is the startup task, it won't run under the dev fabric at all. (Easy way to tell the difference... is the port 80/81/82, or is it 5000+? If the latter, you're not running under the dev fabric.)

csrun /devfabric will open up the dev fabric UI from a command prompt. (Do it from the "Windows Azure SDK Command Prompt" so the path is right.)

Comment: My website is running on port 81 and still can't see dev fabric UI. I also ran csrun /devfabric and dos prompt is showing "Starting the compute emulator...." but I can't see Dev Fabric UI.

Comment: Fixed it now, I used csmonitor.exe from app fabric cmd.